# ModifierKeys does not exist, despite System.Windows.Input being used

Tags: c#, ocr

I'm trying to make a bot that uses OCR and I'm having issues trying to get a hotkey library I found to work.

It uses the ModifierKeys enum as an argument in one of it's functions but apparently 'ModifierKeys doesn't exist'.

I am using System.Windows.Input which should have ModifierKeys in it and I have double checked that I have System.Windows referenced in my project (although that should be pretty obvious since I get no error to do with using System.Windows.Input, I guess)

Here's my current code (error is happening at var key):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using mrousavy;
using System.Windows.Input;
using OCRBot.Handlers;

namespace OCRBot
{
    class Program
    {
        static OCRHandler oCRHandler = new OCRHandler();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("!!");

#if DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress enter to close...");
            Console.ReadLine();
#endif

            var key = new HotKey(
            (ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Alt),
            Key.S,
            this,
            delegate {
                MessageBox.Show("Ctrl + Alt + S was pressed!");
            }
            );

            while (true)
            {
                MainLoop();
            }
        }

        static void MainLoop()
        {
            oCRHandler.ReadWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Reference you want is WindowsBase to get ModifierKeys, not System.Windows.